# Bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently learning for my math exam and I am stuck at the following problem:

> If a real sequence $a_n$ has an upper and a lower boundary $s_u$ and $s_\ell$, then $s=\max\{s_u,s_\ell\}$ is a boundary. Find a counter-example.
>   I need to give $a_n$, $s_u$ and $s_\ell$ so that $s$ is not a boundary.

I have got no idea what they want from me, because if a sequence of elements has a lower and upper boundary, how can the max of these two boundaries not be a boundary.

I'm lost, thanks in advance.

PS: I tried to translate it from German to English so please correct me if i got it wrong. I hope one can understand it.

In german:

Finden Sie ein Gegenbeispiel für die Behauptung "Ist *sl* eine untere und *su* eine obere Schranke, so ist *s:=max{su,so}* eine Schranke."
(Also: *an*, *su* und *sl* angeben, so dass obiges s keine Schranke ist)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by *boundary*? You mean a number that is greater than the absolute values of all $a_n$?

Comment: You probably mean $a_{n}$ has an upper bound of $s_{u}$ and a lower bound of $s_{\ell}$.  By $s$ being a boundary, do you mean a least upper bound?

Comment: You might consider adding the question (in German) below your post here.  Perhaps if another German speaker is here they can assist with the translation.

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, then $s$ is not a "boundary" just because you are not taking into account the fact that numbers can be negative. But that really appears to be just a trick, I hope there is something more serious here.

Comment: Of course numbers can be negative but due to the fact that *s* is is the max out so *su* and *so* it will still always be a bound/boundary
Or am i wrong?

Comment: @giomasce And, yes by boundary i meant a number that is greater than the absolute values of all *an*

Comment: Any lower bound is always smaller than any upper bound. So $s$ will always be $s_u$, independently of $s_\ell$. You probably wanted $s = \max\{|s_u|, |s_\ell|\}$.

Comment: yep that is what i thought as well. But we already proofed that *s=max{|su|,|sl|}* is always true in our lecture. And now i need to find a counter-example to the same statement without the absolute values.

Comment: What about something like $a_{n}=-1+\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq 1$.  Then $s_{u}=0$ is an upper bound and $s_{\ell}=-1$ is a lower bound.  $s=\max\{0, -1\}=0$ but $|a_{n}|>0=s$ for $n>1$.  (I'm not certain I understood the question right.)

Comment: well that would approve for every negative bounded sequence... somehow i can't imagine the problem to be that easy... meh... well i guess i'll ask my tutor and i'll post the answer as soon as i know. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are right, and the question is wrong. If $a$ is a lower bound for a sequence and $b$ is an upper bound, then $\max\{a,b\}=b$, which of course remains as an upper bound.